# Merging two df by column name (not values/int)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to merge two df's by column name

df1:

```
        a           b           c           d           e           f           g


0       NaN       NaN           NaN        NaN          NaN        NaN         NaN
```

df2:

```
        a           b           c           d           e


  0     1         Nan           3           4           5
```

My desired output is:

```
        a           b           c           d           e        f          g


 0      1         Nan           3           4           5       NaN        NaN
```

Comment: Actually this isnt a merge. You just copy one dataframe into the other.

Comment: Check with `combine_first`

Comment: Tried but merge didn't replace it, instead it added df1+df2

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
pd.concat([df2, df1.loc[:, df1.columns.difference(df2.columns)]], axis=1)
```